# Disribute program with scripts in android

Tags: android, android-scripting

I'm confused how the the android scripting enviornment is supposed to work. Is there a relatively easy way to include python scripts that I run from my java code without making the users download any new applications or anything? Or am I completely misunderstanding how ASE works?

Answer (score 0):

This might help a bit, if it is what you meant

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/SharingScripts#Scripts_as_APKs

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. It still require the sl4a executable env, although you packaged your scripts into an APK.